# 0403-057 Syntax error at line 7 : `for' is not matched

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I keep getting a "0403-057 Syntax error at line 7 : `for' is not matched." is not matched error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Please help. Thank you.

```
PASSWORD=$(
        USERNAME="car02fv"
        HOSTS="goxsd1703"
        SCRIPT="pwd; ls"
        for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
            ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}"
        )
        echo "${PASSWORD}"
        done
```

Comment: Which one is exactly line 7 in your file?

Comment: You close your command substitution between `for` and `done`.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ would have helped.

Comment: @BenjaminW. it definitely did. Thank you. I forgot to use `#!/bin/sh` at the top of my file. Thank you.